# Como consigo referenciar resultados filtrados de uma lista no VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Atualmente estou trabalhando em um código onde eu tenho que filtrar uma determinada lista e percorrer os dados filtrados com um FOR e também realizar algumas comparações com o IF. Segue o código

```
Sub compararValores()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim nKm                 As Variant
Dim locBase             As Variant
Dim nmetros             As Variant
Dim ext                 As Variant
Dim exthist             As Variant
Dim sentido             As String
Dim sentidoHistorico    As String
Dim locInicial          As Variant
Dim dateBase            As Date
Dim dateHist            As Date
Dim dateHistProx        As Date
Dim hrHist              As Variant
Dim hrHistProx          As Variant
Dim comp                As Variant
Dim compProx            As Variant
Dim larg                As Variant
Dim largProx            As Variant
Dim esp                 As Variant
Dim espProx             As Variant
Dim faixa               As Variant
Dim faixaProx           As Variant

ext = Base.Range("n2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To ext
    nKm = Base.Range("n" & i).Value
    nmetros = Base.Range("o" & i).Value
    locBase = nKm & "." & nmetros
    sentido = Base.Range("p" & i).Value
    dateBase = Base.Range("d" & i).Value
    dateBaseProx = Base.Range("d" & i + 1).Value

    If (sentido = "N" Or sentido = "n") Then
        sentido = "NORTE"
        Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("$A$1:$AL$30182").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:= _
    "<" & locBase + 5, Operator:=xlAnd
        Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("$A$1:$AL$30182").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:= _
    ">" & locBase - 5, Operator:=xlAnd
    Else
        sentido = "SUL"
        Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("$A$1:$AL$30182").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:= _
    ">" & locBase - 5, Operator:=xlAnd
        Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("$A$1:$AL$30182").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:= _
    "<" & locBase + 5, Operator:=xlAnd
    End If
    
    Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("$A$1:$AL$30182").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=sentido

    exthist = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

    For j = 2 To exthist
    
        With Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").AutoFilter.Range
            teste = Range("r" & .Offset(i, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value2
            locInicial = CStr(Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("q" & .Offset(j, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value2)
            locFinal = CStr(Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("r" & .Offset(j, 0).pecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value2)
            Debug.Print (locInicial)
            Debug.Print (locFinal)
        End With

        sentidoHistorico = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("m" & j).Value
        locInicial = CStr(Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("q" & j).Value)
        locFinal = CStr(Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("r" & j).Value)
        dateHist = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("b" & j).Value
        dateHistProx = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("b" & j + 1).Value
        comp = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("f" & j).Value
        compProx = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("f" & j + 1).Value
        larg = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("g" & j).Value
        largProx = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("g" & j + 1).Value
        esp = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("h" & j).Value
        espProx = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("h" & j + 1).Value
        faixa = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("n" & j).Value
        faixaProx = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("n" & j + 1).Value
        
            If (locBase >= locInicial And locBase <= locFinal) Then
                If (sentido = sentidoHistorico) Then
                    If (dateBase <= dateHist) Then
                        If (dateHist <= dateHistProx) Then
                            If (comp = compProx And larg = largProx And esp = espProx And faixa = faixaProx) Then
                                'i = 3
                                Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("c" & j).Copy
                                Base.Range("ar" & i).PasteSpecial
                                Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("c" & j + 1).Copy
                                Base.Range("au" & i).Offset(0, i).PasteSpecial
                            Else
                                If (faixa <> faixaProx) Then
                                    Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("n" & j).Copy
                                    Base.Range("at" & i).PasteSpecial
                                    Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("c" & j).Copy
                                    Base.Range("au" & i).PasteSpecial
                                End If
                                
                                Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("c" & j).Copy
                                Base.Range("ar" & i).PasteSpecial
                                Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").Range("n" & j).Copy
                                Base.Range("as" & i).PasteSpecial
                                GoTo prox
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If

    Next j
```

prox:
Next i

Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").ShowAllData
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

A minha dúvida é que minhas variáveis `locInicial` e `locFinal` não atualizam os valores ao ir para o próximo J, sempre fica permanente com o primeiro valor da lista filtrada. O resultado esperado para as duas variáveis, seriam os próximos valores da lista.

Comment: Reformule a dúvida, coloque um exemplo de como estão os dados, o resultado esperado e o que você já programou, fica mais fácil e entender e ajudar. Veja: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Atualizada a pergunta

Comment: Ainda tá confuso, sem saber a estrutura inicial e resultado esperado. Mas, pelo que falou está com problema em carregar o valor nas variáveis, tenta simplificar a referência delas, acredito que tem comandos ali que você não deve precisar. Exemplo: de: ".Range("q" & .Offset(j, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value2)" para: ".Range("Q" & j)".

Comment: Agradeço a resposta. Eu atualizei novamente a pergunta.

Comment: Fazendo esta alteração sugerida, o vba não entenderia que estaria me referindo aos valores filtrados e sim para os proximos valores da lista

Comment: Entendi. Sem saber a estrutura inicial dos dados, fica difícil replicar. Talvez tenha problema em executar um For "corrido", sem considerar o Range filtrado somente, offset pode estar prejudicando o endereçamento das células. Uma alternativa seria fazer o For em todas as células, verificando se a linha está visível (com um if) e então executar o código que precisas naquela linha/endereço. Código de exemplo:     For x = 2 To 10
        If Range("A" & x).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            Debug.Print Range("A" & x).Value
        End If
    Next x

Comment: Esta é uma saída boa e agradeço por me direcionar à ela. Eu consegui resolver através de outros métodos semelhantes, contudo, eu gostaria de saber o motivo desta minha sintaxe (mostrada acima na pergunta) não estar funcionando, para assim futuramente não cometer o mesmo erro.